# problems with def draw (not working in my script)

Tags: scripting, add-on

I'm pretty new scripting in blender and I can't figure what's wrong with my script, the goal is to change the active brush and display all the subbrushes linked to this one, the script switch to the brush but that's all it does. Any help will be appreciated.

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "Quick_Brush",
    "author": "Your Name Here",
    "version": (1, 0),
    "blender": (2, 80, 0),
    "location": "View3D > Add > Mesh > New Object",
    "description": "Adds a new Mesh Object",
    "warning": "",
    "wiki_url": "",
    "category": "Add Mesh",
}
import bpy
from bpy.types import  Operator

class Operator (Operator):
    bl_idname='my.operator'
    bl_label='My scale operator'

    def execute(self,context):            
        bpy.ops.wm.tool_set_by_id(name = "builtin_brush.Draw")
        return {'FINISHED'}

    def draw(self, context):
        paint = context.tool_settings.image_paint
        layout = self.layout
        col = layout.column()
        col.template_ID_preview(paint, "brush", rows=3, cols=8, hide_buttons=True)        

class SimpleCustomMenu(bpy.types.Menu):
    bl_label = ""    
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_MT_simple_custom_menu"

    def draw(self, context):        
        layout = self.layout 
        layout.scale_y=0.6
        layout.scale_x=1.6        
        col = layout.column()
        col.operator('my.operator', text = "DRAWG")


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(SimpleCustomMenu)
    bpy.utils.register_class(Operator)
    wm = bpy.context.window_manager
    km = wm.keyconfigs.addon.keymaps.new(name="Image Paint")
    kmi = km.keymap_items.new("wm.call_menu", "A", "RELEASE").properties.name="OBJECT_MT_simple_custom_menu"

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SimpleCustomMenu)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(Operator)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

    bpy.ops.wm.call_menu(name=SimpleCustomMenu.bl_idname)
```

Comment: Hi. You mention in the title that there are problems with `def draw`. What happens? Are there errors, does nothing appear? Please use the [edit] link below the question to add descriptive information about what happens.

Comment: Yes I have problems in my script, that's not a bug report, that part of the code  does nothing and doesn't show an error and i think it should be ok, def draw is where the problem is I suppose